# Updating angularjs ng-repeat with data from firestore

Tags: angularjs, google-cloud-firestore

Html

```
<li ng-repeat="name in $ctrl.names">{{name}}</li>
```

The code below retrieves the data from the firestore database and the top names array is being updated. However, the view is not being populated with the new data. I’ve read up extensively on this question on stackoverflow and elsewhere, but without success. Can anyone help please? Thanks.

```js
let names = [];
this.names = names;
listRef.get()
.then(function(doc) {
  if (doc.exists) {
    names = doc.data().listOfNames;
  }
}
```

Comment: `names = doc.data().listOfNames;` should be `this.names = doc.data().listOfNames;`

Comment: Thanks for your feedback but writing this.names within the function as you suggest returns undefined.

Comment: Can u share some code. i think you are missing `promise` in some way

Comment: The code I’ve shared appears inside my angularjs controller function. Since I’m using the then method I didn’t think I needed to use promise, but I’m probably mistaken. Do you know how to get ng-repeat to update with data from firestore using promise in some way? If so, I’d appreciate a simple example. Thanks.

Comment: @EFlynn Did you check if your `li` get updated when you pass some mock data to your `names` array? Also are you using controller as $ctrl?

Comment: Yes, I’m using $ctrl as controller and the dummy data passes perfectly to the li. Only fails to update when I get the data from firestore as outlined above. Really appreciate your assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a fix. Wrapped the varible I wanted to update in $scope.$apply(). This tells angularjs to watch for updates on $scope.name, which it wasn’t doing before because the $scope.names varible was being updated outside of the angularjs context.

```
$scope.names = [];
listRef.get()
.then(function(doc) {
  if (doc.exists) {
    $scope.$apply(function () {
      $scope.names = doc.data().listOfNames;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this?
I guess you are loosing array reference here.

```
let names = [];
$ctrl = this;
$ctrl.names = names;
listRef.get()
.then(function(doc) {
  if (doc.exists) {
    $ctrl.names = doc.data().listOfNames;
  }
}
```

Comment: Inside `then` whats the console output of $ctrl.name?

Comment: As a possible solution, I’d like to try using $http instead of the firebase get() method to retrieve the data. However, I’m struggling to impliment this approach